# how to assign a class to run with other class only?

Tags: jquery, css

I am new in CSS/JQ and I am trying to make first word in any paragraph is red, I know how to do the basic thing by using [jquery.useWord](https://github.com/melbon/jquery.useWord) , but how to apply it for a specific class?

example: this is the Original class

```
    .post {
    padding: 1px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 9px 0 14px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

I am trying to make any pargraph with class `.post` to be colored red

```
.firstWord {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

any advise?

Comment: How are you doing it now? (what else are you applying it for?)

Comment: I just want to decorate the paragraphs with special color

Comment: No, I'm saying what else have you done with it? How have you used jQuery.useWord?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign that class to `.post` class.

```
$('p.post').addClass('firstWord');
```

You also can add CSS using css method.

```
css("propertyname","value");


$("p.post").css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
```

Comment: @J.Doe Just add above syntax to add the class. In which condition you want to change color where you can add the class if the class already created in CSS otherwise you can add CSS using the second step.